# Python: problem with random seed in random sample

Tags: python, nlp

I have a dataset which the first column is a text, the second one is called author and the third one is called title. So I want to split my dataset into 3 subsamples based on title. Note that there are many different texts with the same title.

```
# Find the unique titles
random.seed(42)
mylist = list(set(list(dt_chunks['title'])))
print(len(mylist))

# Random sample of titles and match all of these titles with the respectively texts
random.seed(42)
trainlist = random.sample(mylist, k = int(len(mylist)*0.7))
pattern = '|'.join(trainlist)
train_idx = dt_chunks['title'].str.contains(pattern)
train_df = dt_chunks[train_idx]

# New list which is contains the other elements that the previous list doesn't contain
random.seed(42)
extralist = list(set(mylist)^set(trainlist))

# same logic
random.seed(42)
validlist = random.sample(extralist, k = int(len(extralist)*0.5))
pattern = '|'.join(validlist)
valid_idx = dt_chunks['title'].str.contains(pattern)
valid_df = dt_chunks[valid_idx]

# same logic
random.seed(42)
testlist = list(set(validlist)^set(extralist))
pattern = '|'.join(testlist)
test_idx = dt_chunks['title'].str.contains(pattern)
test_df = dt_chunks[test_idx]
```

The problem here is that I am using random seed, but if I restart the google colab, the output isn't the same. I would be grateful if you could help me.

Answer (score 0):

Possibly because `dt_chunks['title']` is not the same every time. If this is the case, then `len(mylist)` also changes and `random.sample(mylist, k = int(len(mylist)*0.7))` will lead to the calling of the sampling function internally different number of times on different runs.